# How to find out the changes happened for all objects

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

How I can find out the changes happened in database like modifying functions, table indexes, procedures and adding or removing columns.

Here in this query

```
select * from sys.objects
where type IS NOT NULL
and modify_date between '2013-07-21' and '2013-07-29'
```

but here I am getting created objects list and modifying list, but if I deleted any object it is not showing anything.

How can I get the all the changes happened in database between specific dates?

Comment: Well, if you delete an object, there is no row in sys.objects, since it was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Try a source control solution for SQL.  I've used RedGate's SQL Source Control before, and it records a history of changes like this, including who made the change, and what was changed.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/

It's a bit expensive, but it's good.  I don't know if there's a way to do it (especially deletions) just with SQL itself.

Comment: The challenge here is that if the shop is not already committed to some kind of source control, it's not the easiest of things to just "turn on" - regardless of the quality of offerings.

Comment: We found it pretty easy to just 'turn on' - it really surprised me, because I expected it to be a lot worse.  Massively easier than setting up code-based source control (TFS/SVN/etc).  Can't say for other SQL source control options though, they may indeed be harder.  But, for what we need it for (detecting changes, and then using that to generate change scripts) it was perfect.  Literally got it up and running in 10 minutes.  But, yes, we were used to the concept of source control, so maybe we had an advantage.

Comment: Setting up the software isn't the hard part. It's getting people to change their process. My point is just that this isn't going to be the answer for everyone.

Comment: Oh, I agree 100%.  It was the natural progression for us, but if we tried to do it 2 years ago, it would have fallen flat on its face.

Answer (score 0):

Many of these incidents are recorded in [the default trace](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-default-trace-in-sql-server---the-power-of-performance-and-security-auditing/).

```
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(260);

SELECT 
   @path = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([path]), 
   CHARINDEX(CHAR(92), REVERSE([path])), 260)) + N'log.trc'
FROM    sys.traces
WHERE   is_default = 1;

SELECT 
  LoginName,
  HostName,
  StartTime,
  ObjectName,
  TextData -- may or may not be populated
FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(@path, DEFAULT)
WHERE EventClass IN
(
  164,  -- object:altered
  46,   -- object:created
  47    -- object:deleted
)
AND StartTime >= '20130721' AND StartTime < '20130730';
```

*[Why you should never use `BETWEEN` for date range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).*